# PHP: Why print [object Object]?

Tags: php

I created some post.php file, and I want to load comments count.

But, It occurs to print 'comments_num' is `[object Object]`.

Why is the happening ?

I would really appreciate it if you could help me.

My Code:
post.php

```
$SQL = "SELECT count(*) as comment FROM board_comments where postid={$Rs['postid']}";
$count = $connect->query($SQL)->fetch_array();
$a = $count['comment'];
$post['comments_num'] = $a;
...
```

Comment: Use `fetch_assoc()` instead.

Comment: check by using `print_r($count)` , see what you are getting and how you are trying to access `comment`

Comment: @AmitMerchant I use fetch_assoc, but it same problem .

Comment: @JigarShah print_r is well. But, when you import the values from the React,  will encounter such problems.

Comment: please post o/p of `print_r` or `var_dump` so we can help you better

Comment: Please show us _all_ the relevant code, including the dump _and_ when you output the variable. It's hard to see what happens without knowing what you're actually doing.

Comment: @ko_ma check output of `var_dump($count);` . Put it after `$connect->query($SQL)->fetch_array();` and you will itself come to know why this happen. If not, then show us the output of `var_dump($count);` and we will let you know. Add output in your question not in comment section